# iOS Mobile Push Gateway setup - openssl command implementation

Tags: pubnub

I would like to use the Mobile Push Gateway to send push messages when my app is in the background. I followed this [tutorial](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/objective-c/iOS/tutorial/apple-push-notification.html) and almost done it, but i can't convert the .p12 file to .pem. I could successfully export the .p12 certificate, but can't finish the next steps, maybe i missed something, but can't figure it out.

It's clear that i need to run an openssl command in the Terminal like this:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in <EXPORTED_CERT_NAME.p12> -out <PEM_CERT_NAME.pem> -nodes
```

This is my version:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in <cert.p12> -out <newCert.pem> -nodes
```

`cert.p12` is the exported certificate from the keychain, `newCert.pem` is the new file's name. I've pasted it into the terminal and pressed enter, but nothing happens. Just getting this message `cert2.pem: No such file or directory`.

When i try to check the cert with this command:

```
openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert server_certificates_bundle_sandbox.pem -key server_certificates_bundle_sandbox.pem
```

Get this error:

```
Error opening client certificate private key file server_certificates_bundle_sandbox.pem
2668:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-50/src/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:356:fopen('server_certificates_bundle_sandbox.pem','r')
2668:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-50/src/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:358:
unable to load client certificate private key file
```

What did i wrong? Is it something wrong in my openssl code or i need to do something different in the terminal?

**Update 3**

a, version

```
cd /tmp
openssl pkcs12 -in devKey.p12 -out newDevCert.pem -nodes
  openssl pkcs12 -in devKey.p12 -out newDevCert.pem -nodes
Error opening input file devKey.p12
devKey.p12: No such file or directory
```

b, version

In this case I don't have chance to enter the password, because the error shows up right after the openssl command.

```
cd documents
openssl pkcs12 -in devKey.p12 -out samplePem.pem -nodes
Enter Import Password:
Mac verify error: invalid password?
```

**Update 2**

I tried it without the `< >` in the names

```
 openssl pkcs12 -in developerTest.p12 -out newDevCert.pem -node
```

And it seems something happened

```
openssl pkcs12 -in developerTest.p12 -out newDevCert.pem -node
Usage: pkcs12 [options]
where options are
-export       output PKCS12 file
-chain        add certificate chain
-inkey file   private key if not infile
-certfile f   add all certs in f
-CApath arg   - PEM format directory of CA's
-CAfile arg   - PEM format file of CA's
-name "name"  use name as friendly name
-caname "nm"  use nm as CA friendly name (can be used more than once).
-in  infile   input filename
-out outfile  output filename
....
-keysig       set MS key signature type
-password p   set import/export password source
-passin p     input file pass phrase source
-passout p    output file pass phrase source
-engine e     use engine e, possibly a hardware device.
-rand file:file:...
              load the file (or the files in the directory) into
              the random number generator
-CSP name     Microsoft CSP name
-LMK          Add local machine keyset attribute to private key
```

But when i try to verify it still get an error:

```
Error opening client certificate private key file newDevCert.pem
850:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-50/src/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:356:fopen('newDevCert.pem','r')
850:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-50/src/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:358:
unable to load client certificate private key file
```

**Update (earlier)**

I've exported a new `.p12` certificate and tried it again. If i just open the terminal and run this code:

```
 openssl pkcs12 -in <developerTest.p12> -out <newDevCert.pem> -node
```

Got this error

-bash: developerTest.p12: No such file or directory

I saved `developerTest.p12` into my `Documents` folder, so when i try

```
 cd documents
 openssl pkcs12 -in <developerTest.p12> -out <newDevCert.pem> -node
```

I get a different error:

```
 -bash: newDevCert.pem: No such file or directory
```

In this case I think the answer is a little bit closer, when I run the command inside the `Documents` folder it finds the exported .p12, however something is still wrong.

Is it sure that the `PEM_CERT_NAME` can be anything?

The /tmp version:

```
cd /tmp
openssl pkcs12 -in <developerTest.p12> -out <newDevCert.pem> -node

-bash: developerTest.p12: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. -node should be -nodes (this means "no des")
2. Never use the greater than / less than (< or >) in a filename. The have special meaning in Unix (redirects). When used in instructions, they basically mean, "replace whats between the < and > with your own value, and omit the < and >".

For example, this should work fine:

```
cd /tmp
openssl pkcs12 -in developerTest.p12 -out newDevCert.pem -nodes
```

Let me know if the above works.

Comment: `ls: server_certificates_bundle_sandbox.pem: No such file or directory` I think there was no .pem file created.

Comment: Ok, so verify that "openssl pkcs12 -in <cert.p12> -out <newCert.pem> -nodes" is creating the PEM, and if not, let us know what it says after you run that command. Try it in /tmp as well to be sure its not a write-access permissions issue.

Comment: @vv88 I think I know whats happening here. Two issues, one new, and one old.

Comment: I think I've got it. I could generate the .pem file with this version `openssl pkcs12 -in devKey.p12 -out MyPushApp.pem -nodes -clcerts`. I have no idea what the -clcerts does, is it a proper way to generate the .pem?

Comment: I finished the tut, it's working correctly, I see the welcome message in the console, so it must be ready :).